# get principal spring security from other MicroService

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a problem which I am stuck with it and run out of ideas. I have implemented two Microservers that are running on different ports. one called StaffManager and another called StateManager. StaffManager which manages staff and does spring security for login and saving the user's role etc. StateManager does some work but depends on the user that calls the APIs from StateManager to check if the user is allowed to get some info. or not.
The problem is How StateManager knows who is currently logged in to ask StaffManager Microservice about the role of the user who has currently call the API?

note: using Angular for frontend

Comment: by using token authentication and pass the token in each request.

Comment: Take a look at using JWT with spring security. It's a stateless authentication and authorization mechanism, so if you propagate the token header from the first microserver to the second one, the second one can validate the user and its roles just by examining the token (relying on the token signature), without needing to query the user repository.